# JavaFX Webview : load succeeds but render fails

Tags: java, webview, java-8, javafx-8

I have a Webview (JavaFX 8) that load an article from Wikipedia.

I put a refresh button to allow a refresh, basically, it does another call to the load method of the webEngine of the WebView with the same URL. But about 50% of the time the article is never rendered. In this case, I can right-click on the web view to manually refresh, then it will be rendered successfully.

I tried to look at the LoadWorker state, it always says "SUCCEED"...

Below is a short runnable Test class that demonstrates my point.

```
public class Test1 extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    final WebView webView = new WebView();
    webView.getEngine()
        .load("http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A9cial:Page_au_hasard");
    Tab tab = new Tab("webView", webView);
    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(tab);
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(tabPane);
    Button buttonRefresh = new Button("Refresh");
    buttonRefresh.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        webView.getEngine()
            .load("http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A9cial:Page_au_hasard");
      }
    });
    borderPane.setBottom(buttonRefresh);
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }
```

}

Am I doing something wrong? Does anyone know where this problem might come from?

**EDIT**

I added a few lines to bypass the problem, I check the header in the DOM when the state of the loadWorker becomes SUCCESS. If it is empty, I reload. Now it (looks) 100% ok, but still I am very curious why it didn't simply work all the time first.

**Some thoughts that may be useful**

- The link http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A9cial:Page_au_hasard redirects to a random article (that's why my refresh button can't use `webView.getEngine.reload()`).
- Putting a ChangeListener on the stateProperty of the workLoader to call the reload method of webEngine actually works. Each page is rendered successfully, but already rendered page will also be re-rendered, which is terrible.

Comment: I added a listener to `webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty()` that displayed the new state and the html content when the state was `suceeded`, i.e.  `if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) { System.out.println(webView.getEngine().executeScript("document.documentElement.innerHTML"));}` It seems that when you get a blank result, there really is no html content. So maybe it is a server problem?

Comment: A server problem ? Coming from Wikipedia ?
Anyway, using such a listener to look at the DOM may allow me to see if it is empty or not, and ask a reload if it is. It could be a temporary solution, thx.

Comment: Well, yes, seems unlikely, I admit. The web engine certainly thinks it has received an empty document though. I guess it's possible it's misinterpreting the redirect, but that seems pretty unlikely too. Strange.

Comment: I have ran your code working fine for me.what java version your using and what is your os

Comment: I would add a try-catch to your start method and put the exception to the sysout to see if something happened during the loading. And maybe I would catch the Throwable instead of an Exception...